# do I use sha256sum or sha256hmac for file checksum

Tags: hashsum, checksum

- I have a text file with stuff in it
- I want to checksum it and create a hash for later use to know if the file has changed, when used **anywhere else**
- which to use?   `sha256sum myfile` or `sha256hmac myfile`

Comment: Related QA from Crypto SE: [What is the difference between a HMAC and a hash of data?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6493).

Answer (score 2):

**sha256mac** is to be used with a key.

> sha512hmac - compute and check HMAC values
>
> sha512hmac [-u | -k keyfile | -K key]   file
>
> -k filename:
>
> Use the contents of the specified file as the secret key used in
>                 computing the HMAC values.  If no key file or text is specified,
>                 a  **hard-coded** default value is used.  This option should always
>                 be used.

Executing `sha256hmac myfile.txt` will (a) give a different hash than `sha256sum`, and more importantly, (b) on a given system, **without providing a key** via the -K option, **it will use some hard-coded system value** that is unlikely to be the same on any other system.  Thus, executing `sha256hmac myfile.txt` without specifying a key, the output will be different on different computers; so I think the only reason to use `sha256hmac` without a key is if you want to try and guarantee something can only work or be verified on the computer the hmac hash was generated on {I'm assuming one cannot easily find or get this hard-coded key}.

Simply using `sha256sum myfile.txt` will produce the same hash on any computer system for a given file.

Comment: I actually just tested that theory now: "I think the only reason to use sha256hmac without a key is if you want to try and guarantee something can only work or be verified on the computer the hmac hash was generated on" -- I sha256hmac'd the same file on three machines (fedora 30, fedora 31 and fedora 31), and I got back three times the same HMAC. So it seems to me that generating a value with the 'default' key is basically pointless. Well, in the text you pasted it's written "This option should always be used"...